# Conditional row selection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to select the most applicable (most generic) row from a table

```
CREATE TABLE #T(Id int, Bid int, Did int,Pid int, Vid int, SomeData varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #T
VALUES(1,1,1,1,1,'Data1'),
      (2,1,1,NULL,5,'Data2'),
      (3,1,1,NULL,6,'Data3'),
      (4,1,1,8,NULL,'Data4'),
      (5,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Data5')

SELECT *
FROM #T
```

When I used the parameter values as below, the row I am expecting is with Id 1, As it has the all the values passed from the parameters.

```
DECLARE @Bid INT=1,
        @Did INT=1,
        @Pid INT=1,
        @Vid INT=1
```

When I use below values the row I am expecting is with Id 5. Because there is no row matching Pid 1 and Vid Null. So the most generic row for these parameters are the one with Id =5.

```
DECLARE @Bid INT=1,@Did INT =1,@Pid INT =1,@Vid INT =NULL
```

OR

```
DECLARE @Bid INT=1, @Did INT=1,@Pid INT=1,@Vid INT=6
```

Column value NULL means it can be applicable to any parameter value.

e.g If all has value null mean it is kind of master row. But if master "SomeData" needs to be different, lets say for Vid 1, then we create row will all values null but the Vid  with Value 1.

Priority of the column are from Left to Right.

Also if the values are

```
DECLARE @Bid INT=1,@Did INT =1,@Pid INT =10,@Vid INT =1
```

The expected row is the one with id 5.

I have tried below query but it returns multiple rows. Is there anyway to achieve something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM #T
WHERE ((Bid = @Bid) OR Bid IS NULL) 
    AND ((Did = @Did) OR Did IS NULL)   
    AND ((Pid = @Pid) OR Pid IS NULL)   
    AND ((Vid = @Vid) OR Vid IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to worry about duplicates, i.e. more than one row having the same number of matches, then you can try the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.Id
FROM
(
    SELECT Id,
           CASE WHEN Bid = @Bid OR (Bid IS NULL AND @Bid IS NOT NULL)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BidMatch
           CASE WHEN Did = @Did OR (Did IS NULL AND @Did IS NOT NULL)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DidMatch
           CASE WHEN Pid = @Pid OR (Pid IS NULL AND @Pid IS NOT NULL)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PidMatch
           CASE WHEN Vid = @Vid OR (Vid IS NULL AND @Vid IS NOT NULL)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VidMatch
    FROM #T
) t
ORDER BY t.BidMatch DESC,
         t.DidMatch DESC,
         t.PidMatch DESC,
         t.VidMatch DESC
```

You can just remove the `TOP 1` clause at the beginning of the query to see all IDs sorted descending by how close they match the input variables.

Comment: This is much better. Only issue is the duplicate. If I have the column priority left to right, can we use that to eliminate duplicate?

Comment: What do you mean by left to right?  Can you give a clear example of what you mean?  Keep in mind, ordering this way could get messy because there are so many permutations even with just 4 columns.

Comment: For eg. we are calculating the match count here. If we have two rows  1, 8, 1, NULL and 1, NULL, 1,5 and we are passing parameter values 1,8,NULL,5 both rows will have match count 2. But I am expecting to get the 1st row as result. Because it matches 1,8 in order, before matching 5 as vid in second row. Is this helpful?

Comment: This isn't helpful because you haven't given a system for ranking.  For example, `1, NULL, NULL, NULL` and `NULL, 8, NULL, 5` , with input `1, 8, NULL, 5` ... the first record matches the first, but only the first.  But do two subsequent lesser matches count _more_ or _less_ than a first match?  Hopefully you can see where this is going...

Comment: If I pass `1,1,10,1` it will get the one with id 1 as most matches. But it will be incorrect as that row is specefic to PID-1 and here we looking for PID-10. So this case best match is  last row (with Id 5)

Comment: You didn't answer my query.  If you have two matches, one matching the first column and the other matching the second and fourth columns, which result has higher priority?  Keep in mind that this can get messy due to having 4 columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126502/discussion-between-tim-biegeleisen-and-humpty-dumpty).